# Replace characters in the string with some other characters produce exception

Tags: java, jmeter, beanshell

I'm extracting some value using regular expression say `"Ehj113GPTAw9RMbTgxce2jqh+2rn7tLWFz5JHyhxa+K68ksbE3O5MPvvLU4ihAeaE08DlO7X04MpSVRP7jZIHGv0qPzdmJgwXZUOmVwFWNTQZbpH"`

I want to replace the '+' with '%2B' and send it to the second request as `"Ehj113GPTAw9RMbTgxce2jqh%2B2rn7tLWFz5JHyhxa%2BK68ksbE3O5MPvvLU4ihAeaE08DlO7X04MpSVRP7jZIHGv0qPzdmJgwXZUOmVwFWNTQZbpH"`

How can I achieve this?

I have already tried `replaceAll` and `replace` but I'm going wrong somewhere.

```
var Connect = vars.get("92_ConnectionToken").toString();
log.info(Connect);
String ConnectToken = Connect.replaceAll("+", "%2B");
String ConnectFinal = ConnectToken.replaceAll("/", "%2F");
vars.put("92_ConnectionToken", ConnectFinal);
log.info(ConnectFinal);
```

Expected result:

```
Ehj113GPTAw9RMbTgxce2jqh%2B2rn7tLWFz5JHyhxa%2BK68ksbE3O5MPvvLU4ihAeaE08DlO7X04MpSVRP7jZIHGv0qPzdmJgwXZUOmVwFWNTQZbpH.
```

This string should be sent as the input to the second request.

Actual Result:

```
2019-05-13 10:37:22,343 ERROR o.a.j.u.BeanShellInterpreter: Error invoking bsh method: eval Sourced file: inline evaluation of: `` var Connect = vars.get("92_ConnectionToken").toString(); log.info(Connect); Str . . . '' : Typed variable declaration : Method Invocation Connect.replaceAll
2019-05-13 10:37:22,343 WARN o.a.j.m.BeanShellPreProcessor: Problem in BeanShell script. org.apache.jorphan.util.JMeterException: Error invoking bsh method: eval   Sourced file: inline evaluation of: `` var Connect = vars.get("92_ConnectionToken").toString(); log.info(Connect); Str . . . '' : Typed variable declaration : Method Invocation Connect.replaceAll.
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use `String` specific methods as `replaceAll`, define variable as `String`:

```
String Connect = vars.get("92_ConnectionToken");
```

You need to escape regex special characters as `+`

```
String ConnectToken = Connect.replaceAll("\\+", "%2B");
```

As @kumesana commented, you better use `replace` method:

```
String ConnectToken2 = Connect.replace("+", "%2B");
```

Comment: Error invoking bsh method: eval Sourced file: inline evaluation of: ``String Connect = vars.get("92_ConnectionToken").toString(); log.info(Connect); S . . . '' : Typed variable declaration : Method Invocation Connect.replaceAll
 WARN o.a.j.m.BeanShellPreProcessor: Problem in BeanShell script. org.apache.jorphan.util.JMeterException: Error invoking bsh method: eval Sourced file: inline evaluation of: ``String Connect = vars.get("92_ConnectionToken").toString(); log.info(Connect); S . . . '' : Typed variable declaration : Method Invocation Connect.replaceAll. Still getting above error

Comment: @Yadnesh , added to answer `String ConnectToken = Connect.replaceAll("\\+", "%2B");`

Comment: Or, you know, replace() instead of regex-oriented replaceAll()

Comment: replaceAll() is very ill-named. replace() will replace everything too.